# Why is PropertyState Necessary

Tags: gradle

Suppose I'm developing a Gradle plugin and the inputs that some of the tasks the plugin configures depend on how it is configured via an extension. For example:

```
class MyTask extends DefaultTask {
    @InputFile
    File toTrack

    @TaskAction
    def run() {
        println("The file now contains ${toTrack.text}")
    }
}

class MyConfig {
    File toTrack = new File('bad-default.txt')
}

class MyPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
    @Override
    def apply(Project project) {
        project.with {
            extensions.create('config', MyConfig)
            task('printChanges', type: MyTask) {
                toTrack = config.toTrack
            }
        }
     }
}
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work correctly. The problem is that if I have a build.gradle like:

```
apply plugin: my-plugin

config {
   toTrack = file('file-to-track.txt')
}
```

where I've specified a file to track, Gradle will evaluate the `@InputFile` on my task **before** the `config` block is run so it'll decide if the task is up to date or not by looking at `bad-default.txt` rather than `file-to-track.txt`.

The recommended fix to this seems to be to use [`PropertyState`](https://docs.gradle.org/4.1/userguide/custom_plugins.html#sec:mapping_extension_properties_to_task_properties) like so:

```
class MyTask extends DefaultTask {
    PropertyState<File> toTrack = project.property(File)

    @InputFile
    File getToTrack { return toTrack.get() }

    @TaskAction
    def run() {
        println("The file now contains ${toTrack.get().text}")
    }
}

class MyConfig {
    private PropertyState<File> toTrack 

    MyConfig(Project project) {
        toTrack = = project.property(File)
        toTrack.set('bad-default.txt')
    }

    void setToTrack(File fileToTrack) { toTrack.set(fileToTrack) }
}

class MyPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
    @Override
    def apply(Project project) {
        project.with {
            extensions.create('config', MyConfig)
            task('printChanges', type: MyTask) {
                toTrack = config.toTrack
            }
        }
     }
}
```

That works but it seems very verbose and the `PropertyState` stuff seems entirely unnecessary. It seems like the real fix was simply to change the `@InputFile` annotation to be on a getter instead of having it be on the property. In other words, I believe the following has the same effect and is less code and easier to understand:

```
class MyTask extends DefaultTask {
    File toTrack

    // This is the only change: put the annotation on a getter
    @InputFile
    File getToTrack() { return toTrack }

    @TaskAction
    def run() {
        println("The file now contains ${toTrack.text}")
    }
}

class MyConfig {
    File toTrack = new File('bad-default.txt')
}

class MyPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
    @Override
    def apply(Project project) {
        project.with {
            extensions.create('config', MyConfig)
            task('printChanges', type: MyTask) {
                toTrack = config.toTrack
            }
        }
     }
}
```

With some experiments this does seem to have the desired effect. What am I missing? Is there ever a time when `PropertyState` is necessary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not the time `@InputFile` is evaluated. `@InputFile` is evaluated just before the task is executed, so *after* the configuration phase has finished and *during* gradles execution phase. The problem `PropertyState` is solving is the wiring between an extension and a task.

let's look again on your apply method:

`def apply(Project project) {
    project.with {
        extensions.create('config', MyConfig)
        task('printChanges', type: MyTask) {
            toTrack = config.toTrack
        }
    }
}`

here you:

1) Create your custom extension with the default value provided in the `MyConfig` class.

2) Link the value *currently* set in `MyConfig` to the `MyTask` toTrack property.

Now looking at the plugin usage:

```
apply plugin: my-plugin

config {
    toTrack = file('file-to-track.txt')
}
```

here you:

1) Apply the plugin (and basically executing the apply method of your plugin).

2) Reconfigure the `MyConfig#toTrack` extension property.

But what isn't happening here, is updating the value in the `printChanges` task. That's what `PropertyState` is solving. It has nothing todo with Task inputs and outputs evaluation.

Comment: Doh! Yup, that definitely makes sense. At some point I had a setup where the file being used for up-to-date check was wrong but if I forced tasks to run the correct file was processed. That got my thinking all muddled. That was a few code changes ago and I'm not sure how I had things set up. Thanks for the clarification.